# Разработка игр под iOS в unity3D

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Наверное это глупый вопрос, но все же, мучает меня давно: Можно ли разрабатывать игры в Unity под iOS, не используя при этом iPhone/iPad и работая только на Windows?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 1):

Разрабатывать можно, но для сборки нужен Mac или билдить, используя их [сервис](https://developer.cloud.unity3d.com/support/guides/ios/).

Comment: Просто для Windows в Unity нет как таковой поддержки iOS. Это может иметь последствия в процессе разработки?

Comment: @НазарМазурик может. Но обычно последствия минимальны.